# Обновление всех записей в БД (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Привет!

У меня в базе имеются поля `date`и `date_unix`. Поле `date` (`varchar(100)`) хранит в записях дату по типу *1.10.2017, 12.05.2016* и так далее. Но поле `date_unix` у всех пустое.

Как можно максимально быстро средствами PHP обновить данные (перевести в Unix) `date_unix` каждой записи, в зависимости от `date`.

То есть, если `date = '1.10.17'`, то `date_unix = '1506808800'`.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее тут и PHP не нужно, можно просто выполнить запрос:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date_unix` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d.%m.%y')) WHERE `date_unix` IS NULL
```

P.S. Лучше сделайте бэкап таблицы, но запрос вроде бы как верный.

Comment: можно и без where и бэкапа, написано что поле пустое везде

Comment: Вроде заработало, но если проверять через онлайн конвертер, то на 27.11.2017 показывает 26.11.2017 23:00.

Спасибо большое!